# Trouble creating view with concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)

Tags: mysql

I have created the following SQL and I keep getting:
ERROR 1583 (42000): Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'. I am sure it is something simple but I have been staring at this so long I decided to ask you kind folks what I am doing wrong.

```
CREATE VIEW customer_info AS
  SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ‘ ‘, last_name) AS full_name,
    customer_id,
    street_address,
    city,
    state,
    zip,
    home_phone,
    mobile_phone,
    other_phone
FROM customers;
```

Comment: replace the backticks `‘ ‘` with `''`

Comment: This is why word processors make terrible IDEs.

Comment: Wow yeah copy and paste strikes again

Comment: I was copying from google docs and I guess it was changing the single quotes to backticks. Super annoying.

Comment: Always use a syntax-highlighting editor as it can spot mistakes like this.